# Open .sav file in excel after converting it to .csv online

Tags: excel, csv, export, spss

I am trying to process a data base, which is in .sav format, on excel. 
I have converted sav to csv online: through http://pspp.benpfaff.org/ but I get csv text, not a file.

How can I import this into excel so that it reads it as columns? otherwise I have the text in commas.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening CSV files in Excel 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402781/opening-csv-files-in-excel-2016)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the easiest method after online conversion is to save the resulting text as a .txt file. From there you will open Excel-->File-->Import

If your data has headers you will select that option, but the main thing is to set the delimiter as comma and then hit finish. It should retain the data structure initially found in your SPSS file.