# Workbooks.OpenText not parsing csv files properly Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-2016

I'm pretty sure this worked properly in previous versions of Excel

Test File:

```
d/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
5/12/1999 6:01:12
30/11/2001 5:00:00
```

And the delimiter between the date and the time is a Space (ASCII code 32)

- If the file is saved as a `.txt` file, the OpenText method parses properly.
- If the file is saved as a `.csv` file, the OpenText method doesn't seem to work at all
- If the spaces are replaced with commas, and the file is saved as a `.csv` file, the OpenText method will split the lines into two columns, but will not properly interpret the date string.

My Windows Regional Settings are mdy and my Excel version is 2016

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim sFN As String
    Dim FD As FileDialog

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Text or CSV", "*.txt, *.csv", 1
    .Show
    sFN = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFN, DataType:=xlDelimited, origin:=437, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlDMYFormat), Array(2, xlGeneralFormat))


Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Without know what other columns you have, it seems like you could just read the date and time as a single Date column. It seems likely that is what Excel is doing with the CSV file anyway.

Comment: `.Filters.Add "Text or CSV", "*.txt, *.csv", 1` Hm, no, `CSV` and `Text` are really **not** the same for `Excel`. Not only that the delimiter settings are very special for `CSV` and are **not** setable using a parameter in `Workbooks.OpenText`, also the unicode handling is a very special case for `CSV` and is signly different from `Text`.

Comment: @ThunderFrame That won't work without changing my Windows Regional Settings.

Comment: @AxelRichter I thought it used to work in 2007, but I no longer have this available for testing.  Also, in the native Excel File Open dialog, text files are listed as `Text Files (*.prn,*.txt,*.csv)`.  In 2016 VBA, it only seems to fail if the file suffix is `.csv`. Other suffixes, or even files with no suffix, succeed.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: Does also not work using Excel 2007. Believe it or not, `CSV` is **not** simply text for `Excel`. There is even an undocumented parameter `sep=` at the beginning of the file to change the expected delimiter. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Application_support.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for testing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for suggestions. Amongst the possible solutions, I decided, for my purposes, to remove the `*.csv` suffix from the file.  This works and can be adaptable.  `QueryTable` method would also work, along with the caveats posted by Axel.

Here is code that works for my method, if anyone is interested.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim WB As Workbook, wbCSV As Workbook, swbCSV As String
    Dim sFN As String, sCopyFN
    Dim FD As FileDialog

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Text or CSV", "*.txt, *.csv", 1
    .Show
    sFN = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'If CSV, remove suffix
sCopyFN = ""
If sFN Like "*.csv" Then
    sCopyFN = Left(sFN, Len(sFN) - 4)
    FileCopy sFN, sCopyFN
    sFN = sCopyFN
End If

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFN, DataType:=xlDelimited, origin:=437, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlDMYFormat), Array(2, xlGeneralFormat))

Set wbCSV = ActiveWorkbook

'Get path as string since it will not be available after closing the file
swbCSV = wbCSV.FullName

'Move the data into this workbook
Dim rCopy As Range, rDest As Range

With WB.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
End With
Set rCopy = wbCSV.Sheets(1).UsedRange

rCopy.Copy rDest

'must close the file before deleting it
wbCSV.Close False
Kill swbCSV

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this might be the same issue addressed in this thread:

[Opening CSV files in Excel 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402781/opening-csv-files-in-excel-2016)

> CSV files are Character Separated Value files, not Comma separated.
>   For more than half the world the separator character is semicolon (;),
>   not a comma (,)
>
> Excel 2016 properly respects your Windows regional settings, and uses
>   the specified "List separator" character
>
> One solution is to change your regional settings for the "List
>   separator" attribute to the character you want Excel to default to
>   using, e.g. a comma (,)
>
> This can be changed in:
>
> Control Panel / Region / Additional Settings / List separator:

Comment: That problem did not reference the `OpenText` method nor issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

`CSV` and `Text` are really **not** the same for `Excel`. Not only that the delimiter settings are very special for `CSV` and are **not** setable using a parameter in `Workbooks.OpenText`. Also other parameters like field types (`FieldInfo`) will also not be respected while opening `CSV` files. And also the unicode handling is a very special case for `CSV` and is signly different from `Text`.

You could try using `QueryTables` like so:

```
Sub foo1()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim sFN As String
    Dim FD As FileDialog

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Text or CSV", "*.txt, *.csv", 1
    .Show
    sFN = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set WB = Workbooks.Add

With WB.Worksheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & sFN & "", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "test"
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlDMYFormat, xlGeneralFormat)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

But using QueryTables of course you must be careful not adding them multiple times without necessary but refreshing them instead or first deleting them and then adding them again.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using the `Query Tables` method.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidating my experimentation and Axel Richter's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42198852/2026637 with dwirony's answer to a related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55166268/2026637 :

1. Import of a CSV file having a .csv extension by `OpenText` or by `Open` treats all dates as MDY (American) format.
2. `OpenText` ignores all format options with a CSV file having a .csv extension.
3. With a CSV file having a .txt extension and using the `xlDelimited` option, `OpenText` takes account of the `FileInfo` parameter, but the column numbers are ignored, so an array element must be present for each column starting from 1 until all columns with non-default formats are described.

It's frustrating that the user interface works correctly (including defaulting to the regional date format), but the VBA interface has these problems.

The problems are present in Excel 2013 as well as Excel 2016.

Comment: I agree. I've "defaulted" to using Power Query for the import. Doesn't matter if it's .txt or .csv (or .???).  One can inform PQ of the incoming date format, and it will handle it properly unless you change the query. Refreshing is also straightforward.