# LaravelExcel: Interface 'App\Exports\FormView' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am working with Laravel 5.8 with PHP 7.4 to develop my project, and in this project, I wanted to make an Excel file out of a table called `students` from View.

So here is what I did:

I typed `composer require maatwebsite/excel` at the Terminal and downloaded the package.

I added `\Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,` in `providers` at `config/app.php`, and `'Excel' => \Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,` as `aliases`.

And then made this new Export file:

```
php artisan make:export StudentExportView --model=App\Member\Student
```

And this file holds this:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Member\Student;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FormView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class StudentExportView implements FormView
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('admin.students.custom', [
            'customs' => Student::all()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And at the Controller, I have added this method:

```
public function export_view()
{
    return Excel::download(new StudentExportView, 'students.xlsx');
}
```

And also these routes to `web.php`:

`Route::get('export_view','StudentAdminController@export_view')->name('students.export_view');`

But when I it out, I get this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
> (E_ERROR)
>
> Interface 'App\Exports\FormView' not found

So what's going wrong here?

### Note

If I remove `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FormView;` from Export Class, an *empty* excel file downloads

And the package is  `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"`

Comment: Check this https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html

Comment: Have you placed your blade file inside `admin/students/custom.blade.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `FromView` not `FormView`.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class StudentExportView implements FromView
```

Comment: Thank u mate, would u take a look at this question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426134/laravelexcel-takes-too-much-of-time-and-not-exporting-any-data